# Название алгоритма проверки изображения

Tags: c#, puzzle

Кто может подсказать алгоритм проверки изображения на оригинальность. Нужно это для игры пазлы, где на вход в программу даются уже разбитые картинки. Про полную картинку программа ничего не знает